# make the Fragment invisible when initialized

Tags: android

I have an activity which contain two `Fragment`, now I want them invisible when the `Activity` is created, I will show the Fragment according to the user input.

So  I tried to set the `Fragment` invisbile in the layout file:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.app.ui.ArticleListFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/poiSearchFrag"
    android:visibility="gone"></fragment>

<fragment
    android:name="com.app.ui.ArticleReaderFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/routeSearchFrag"
    android:visibility="gone"></fragment>
```

But it seems that this does not work.

How to fix it?

Comment: what does "it seems not work" mean

Comment: When the Activity started, both of the Fragment is visible.

Comment: try to use the fragmenttransaction's hide() method programatically instead..

Comment: you can always set to gone the view inside the fragments, instead of  the fragments one

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the fragments in different layouts and then use layout.setVisibility property to change the visibility based on user input. So the layout will be :

```
Layout1
  |
  Fragment 1
Layout2
  |
  Fragment 2
```